# @Bean alternative in jersey

Tags: java, spring, jersey, jax-rs

I want to create a bean of thread pools using Executor. In spring I can use @Bean inside @Configuration annotated class. What is the **alternative** in Jersey?

Also when the application shuts off then in Spring I can use @PreDestroy in that same configuration class to shut down the thread pool, any alternative to this in Jersey?

Answer (score 0):

Both [javax.annotation.PostConstruct](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) and [javax.annotation.PreDestroy](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PreDestroy.html) work for beans managed by Jersey.

For the `@Beans` alternatives, you can use [HK2 mechanism](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest31x/ioc.html#d0e17546) for creating beans, or you can use Jersey alternatives with the same names, for instance in [this tutorial](https://riptutorial.com/jersey/example/23632/basic-dependency-injection-using-jersey-s-hk2).

Or you could have CDI managed environment (such as in the application server), where you can use [CDI producers](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#producer_method) to produce CDI beans, that could be injected with `@Inject`.